# HP Elitebook 8460p use external keyboard to boot up

Tags: laptop, keyboard, boot

I am using an Elitebook 8460p with an external wireless keyboard and mouse.  I have a second monitor that is a duplicate of the laptop's display and I just keep the lid closed and use the monitor.

I do not have a docking station.

It would be great if I could use the external keyboard to boot the system up so that I don't have to open the lid, press the button, close the lid every time I want to boot up the machine.

I have looked in the BIOS for the power management tools but I cannot find it in there to set the keyboard shortcut, and am running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you can't, simply because your keyboard is not prioritized in the BIOS boot-up section, it's a peripheral its means it will be loaded after the system boots up, so you can't boot from it.

+1 if it helped, thanks.

Comment: @George never mind brother, am here for any help ... cheers :)